# Excel custom DateTime formatting to remove time if not time is zero (00:00:00)

Tags: excel, date, format

I am looking for custom DateTime format which allows me to remove the time for dates where time is zero (00:00:00).
The reason for this is that I have some sheets with many DateTime columns, some of these columns time is essential and come with it, whereas others time is not necessary and comes as 00:00:00.

```
Sample:
Date/Time               Desired result
====================    =====================
22/05/2017 08:30:15     22/05/2017 08:30:15
23/05/2017 00:00:00     23/05/2017
24/05/2017 00:00:00     24/05/2017
25/05/2017 08:30:15     25/05/2017 08:30:15
```

The idea is to apply this custom format to all Date/Time columns.

Thanks

Comment: This question probably better suited to SuperUser: https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are dealing with an older version of Excel, you can do this with Conditional Formatting.

- Format the cells as `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`
- Then set up conditional formatting with a formula

  - `=A2=INT(A2)`
  - Format ► Number ► Custom ► `dd/mm/yyyy`